# Como fazer downloads pelo Delphi por servidores FTP com autenticação?

Tags: delphi, ftp, download, delphi-xe6

Tenho alguns arquivos em um servidor FTP no Hostinger, e estes arquivos foram deixados lá visto que links de servidores FTP nunca mudam. Como eles são muito importantes para fazer atualizações na minha aplicação, o Delphi deve baixá-los.

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi você está usando?

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser feito com o componente **TIdFTP**.

Por exemplo:

```
IdFTP1.Disconnect();

IdFTP1.Host := 'ftp.seuftp.com';
IdFTP1.Port := 21;
IdFTP1.Username := 'usuario';
IdFTP1.Password := 'senha';
IdFTP1.Passive := true;
   
IdFTP1.Connect(true, 10000);    

IdFTP1.Get (arquivoNoServidor, arquivoDestino, true, false);
```

[Fonte](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/fazendo-download-e-upload-usando-ftp.html)